# Force update in a a PWA with NetworkFirst policy

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA built with ReactJS and I have the NetworkFirst policy handled by Workbox, so when I update the front, the service worker detects a new version and download it in the background and this new version is applied only in two cases: when the browser is closed and opened or after 24 hours, here is the code of my service-worker.

```
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js');
    /* global workbox */
    if (workbox) {
        console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
        workbox.core.skipWaiting();
        workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]); // URLs to precache injected by workbox build
        workbox.routing.registerRoute(
            new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(
                new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
                    cacheName: 'PRODUCTION',
                })
            )
        );        
    } else {
        console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it is posible with this policy, to do a release that makes an instant update and doesn't need to wait till the service-worker do the update at the next day.

Thanks!!

Comment: NetworkFirst should get the latest version from the network, update the cache, and use it in the current render. Are you not seeing that behavior?

Comment: No, I am having the new version captured by the service worker but it is not updated till next day or till the browser closed and opened

Comment: It sounds like NetworkFirst is not actually being used then.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are specifying any routes or resources for NetworkFirst so all requests are probably being handled by precacheAndRoute.